# email address extraction

Tags: php, email

I would like a php script, i imagine it will need sql for storage, that logs in to my gmail goes through all my emails and extracts the to from and cc and the email addresses within the text of the email, from forwarded and multiply forwarded emails, and tags them as where the came from ie to from cc and inline.

whats the best way to go about it i have no idea where to start

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pseudocode using PHP - each step should be simple enough to implement on its own.

- connect to database using the [`mysqli` extension](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
- [log into gmail](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php) using the [`imap` extension](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) and its functions

  - [get a list of folders](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-list.php)
  - for each folder

    - get a list of messages, [and their headers](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headers.php)
    - for each message (you may want to check and reject obvious spam here)
    - get [message headers](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php) and [body](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-body.php)
    - look for the From: To: CC: and BCC: headers
    - store those into database (those are your tags)
    - use a [regular expression](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) to match possible e-mail addresses
    - if matches found:

      - store them into database, linked with the tags
- disconnect from gmail
- disconnect from database

Comment: It's a good answer, but not sure we should be encouraging such poor questions.

Comment: @Richard: IMHO it's borderline (apart from the grammar); IMAP and e-mail handling can be quite confusing. Note that I have provided pointers, not a complete solution.

Comment: your both correct its a poor question, but imap and email handling do have a steep learning curve, the grammar however is inexcusable

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good place to start:

http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/